# Limit of brownian local time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let $(B_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion and $(\phi(t,0))_{t \geq 0}$ be its local time at $0$.
Then does it hold that $\lim_{t \uparrow \infty}\phi(t,0)=\infty$ almost surely?

Comment: I think this is almost immediate from the recurrence of Brownian motion and the strong Markov property.

Answer (score 1):

A non-Markovian approach: By Tanaka's formula, assuming $B_0=0$, you have $|B_t| = W_t +\phi(t,0)$, where $W$ is another Brownian motion. Thus
$$
\phi(t,0)=|B_t|-W_t\ge -W_t.
$$
We know that the Brownian motion $W$ will eventually hit any  $b\ll 0$. Because $t\mapsto \phi(t,0)$ is increasing
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\phi(t,0)\ge -b,\qquad\forall b<0,
$$
almost surely.